# Does this question really involve trivia?

Tags: discussion

**Now reopened**

---

After posting this question here:

[Frida Kahlo, Warhol, Klimt, Picasso - Which other artists are referenced in the Hey Duggee 'Art Badge' episode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/109413/frida-kahlo-warhol-klimt-picasso-which-other-artists-are-referenced-in-the?noredirect=1#comment185942_109413)

I revised it so that it properly explains how the visual refrences within the minifilm are essential to being able to properly understand or appreciate the episode. However, it still got closed (possibly, I made the edits too late). In the close reason it states:

> > Trivia questions that do not add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie/TV-show are off-topic.

This does not seem to me to be the case here. Is the real problem that at first glance this is a childrens' animation? I don't really see how a question relating to the central theme of a film can be deemed 'trivia'.

As a seasoned contributor on other SE sites, I do understand the need for maintaining the quality and relevance of questions. However, I have to admit, I'm  a bit perplexed with regards to the close reason for this question here.

Comment: I don't believe the closure was anything to do with it being a kids' TV show. I expect that, had it been about a TV-MA show or a highbrow film, it would have attracted close votes all the same. (Note that doesn't mean the close-voters were necessarily *correct*, just that their incorrectness would have had nothing to do with your question being about a kids' show.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the question has been treated a bit harshly indeed. The "trivia" close-reason is precisely to protect against empty brand identification that contributes nothing to the appreciation of the work. Yet you make a good case for why it is relevant to the episode, especially since it's an educational program.

While we do need the close-reason to protect against empty IMDb lookups and irrelevant "what car's that dude driving" things, this community has also grown a bit over-anxious about possible trivia questions over the years, in addition to the general inability of SE sites to operate effectively on somewhat vaguer rules. I would argue there could certainly be made a good case for your question not being such in its current form. Add to this, that your improvements in this regard also came after it had already attracted close- and downvotes, and there can be somewhat of a bandwagoning effect in these cases. I don't think it had much to do with it being a kids' show, though.

But another problem that adds to this is, that it has also been downvoted to quite some degree, for the same reasons of a community having grown tired of low-quality contributions. While this certainly needs to be dealt with in the bigger picture, in your specific case this also means even if we reopen that question, we will end up with an open but unjustifiably low-scored question since there's not a big chance all the people downvoting it will revert their votes after seeing your possible improvements. So it's really difficult to decide what to best do with that question now and to be honest, maybe deleting it and rewriting it entirely (especially with emphasizing the educational viewpoint) would even be preferable, although I know that means quite a bit more work for you.

I'm really sorry that this happened, but I think you got jumped on a bit here.

Comment: I haven't downvoted it nor voted to close it, but I do fear the question can result in numerous answers where each identifies one or more works of art. I watched a small clip of this episode on YT and saw at least half a dozen works of art they referenced, so I hesitate to think what the full episode contains. Perhaps OP could start an answer themselves, providing screenshots for the various works of art from the show and provide answers for those they recognize, allowing others to fill in the rest. Asking us to watch the episode (and create screenshots) is a bit much, IMHO.

Comment: I thought this was a valid question under the first listed on-topic suggestion in the help centre; “Analysis of content or theme of all forms of movies and TV series“.